# nsIProperty.get to something other than nsIFile - fastest way to get special path strings

Tags: firefox-addon

Is it possible to use nsIProperty.get to get special path into something other than a nsIFile? I tried nsISupportsString but it doesnt work. There's gotta be something other than nsIFile it should get on right, why else would they make it an argument?

Im looking for the fastest way to get special path strings, because this stuff is happening on a 200ms animation of a panel element these times are critical to me.

Heres some speed analysis:

```
// FileUtils.jsm :: getFile
// average time: 3.85ms
console.time('path'); var path = FileUtils.getFile('DefProfRt', []).path; console.timeEnd('path'); console.log(path);

// nsIDirectoryService :: nsIProperties :: get - nsIFile
// average time: 0.07ms
console.time('path'); var path = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIProperties).get('DefProfRt', Ci.nsIFile).path; console.timeEnd('path'); console.log(path);


// OS.Constants.Path
// average time: 0.12ms
console.time('path'); var path = OS.Constants.Path.profileDir; console.timeEnd('path'); console.log(path);
```

I don't get why OS.Constants.Path takes longer than nsIProperties.get as OS.Constants.Path is hardcoded I thought.

Comment: If you need this string in your time-critical code, why not perform this operation prior to the time-critical period? Is the actual thing you are getting something that depends on user input during the critical time-period? This could be done as a part of startup, or after activation, but prior to the animation starting. If it is done at startup and is not something that needs to be done in order for the Firefox UI to be shown, it can easily be delayed until after the Firefox UI is active and available to the user by putting it in a function which is called after a delay.

Comment: Thanks Mayken, I was just making up an excuse as I thought no one would reply otherwise :P I'm just trying to get as fast as possible :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three ways end to the same native code, but the `nsIDirectoryService` approach involves less javascript than the other two.

You can't get any faster, nsIFile is not a bottleneck here since no filesystem operation occurs. Merely string concatenation.

If 0.07ms is not good enough, you 're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks its good enough but I was just looking for the fastest. I was wondering if you knew why OS.Constants takes longer than nsIDirectoryService? I thought that was the least js method.

Comment: Also i was wondering why the second argument to `get` when its always `nsIFile`?

Comment: It's not always `nsIFile`. `AChromDL`, `APluginsDL` and `SrchPluginsDL` return instances of `nsISimpleEnumerator`. Also this makes the service more flexible and open to future extensions.

Comment: Oh super cool thanks man! I'll search those on MXR :) How did you know they returend nsISimpleEnumerator I can't find them on mxr :( http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/search?string=AChromDL